# Saving text from Textarea in mysql database with php (apostrophes)

Tags: php, mysql

html

```
<form id = "recall_TextArea2" method="post" action="SaveRecall2.php">
    <center><textarea name="recall_Info" cols="60" rows="30em"></textarea></center>
</form>
```

php

```
if (isset($_POST['recall_Info'])) {
    $recall_Info = $_POST['recall_Info'];
}
else {
    echo "nothing was recalled.";
}

$recall_Info = stripslashes($recall_Info);
$recall_Info = mysqli_real_escape_string($recall_Info);
$update_sql = "UPDATE  `participants` SET  `recall_1` =  '$recall_Info' WHERE  `school_id` =825776 LIMIT 1 ;";
```

I want to be able to type in text in the text area that has apostrophes, but every time i try, it doesn't work.

It saves normal text (no apostrophes) when i take out

```
$recall_Info = stripslashes($recall_Info);
$recall_Info = mysqli_real_escape_string($recall_Info);
```

Comment: Is that extra pair of `''` just a typo?

Comment: i wish that was the problem. i took them out and it still didn't work.

Comment: Is the record just not being updated?  Also, what data type is `school_id`?

Comment: in the database, school_id is an int(6)

Comment: You are comparing it to a string in your WHERE clause.  If you remove the quotes from around the id, does it update properly?

Comment: So... were those single quotes a typo in the question?

Comment: still doesn't work. It does, however, enter normal text (no apostrophes) when i remove
`$recall_Info = stripslashes($recall_Info);`
`$recall_Info = mysqli_real_escape_string($recall_Info);`

Comment: Just save yourself all escaping problems and use a prepared statement with bound variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say see if you are accessing your form/post data properly. Maybe echo out your form data  before the sql to see what's going on.

This worked for me, I didn't change your sql query:

```
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "test";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

$recall_Info ="this is new recall info text";

$update_sql = "UPDATE  `participants` SET  `recall_1` =  '$recall_Info'  '' WHERE       `school_id` ='825776' LIMIT 1;";

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($update_sql);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
$OK = true;
}
if ($OK) {
echo 'update successful';
}
```

Comment: it works with apostrophes if you add stripslashes() and mysql_real_escape_string();